# How to MLE/MAP estimate a parameter of a Beta distribution, fixed the other?

Tags: r, parameters, mle

Let's assume a Beta distribution in `(a,b)` and let's assume a variable `X` defined in `(0,1)`.

Fix `b` to a number `y_1`.

What would you do to estimate the number `y_2` that minimise the errors between `f(Beta(y_2,y_1))` and in `f(x)in`.
Here in `f` is the frequency function, PDF for the Beta and empirical for X.

I don't care if the error is big or small compared to other parameterisations in in `Beta(a,b)`, it only has to be an approximate minimum given fixed `b1`.

Minimal reproducible example:

```
X <- rbeta(n = 10000, shape1 = 5, shape2 = 1)
library(EstimationTools)
y <- maxlogL(X,
             "dbeta",
             fixed = list(shape2 = 1),
             link = list(over = "shape1", fun = "log_link"))
y
```

How would you improve this code or would you suggest other packages?

(also I am interested in how to improve this in other languages)

Comment: This question needs a [mcve], and really should have 1 language tagged, not 3.

Answer (score 1):

This really sounds like part of the problem statement got dropped. Normally, the beta distribution arises because it is conjugate to the binomial distribution. The binomial has to do with the probability of observing some number of successes in `n` trials, each with a probably `p` of success.

If you observe `k` successes in `n` trials, then the MLE for `p` is `k/n`. If you have knowledge about the prior in the form `p ~ Beta(α, β)` then the posterior distribution will be `p ~ Beta(α + k, β + n-k)`.

In such a situation it might make (a bit of) sense to suppose that you know β and are only uncertain about α. I think you can just get the closed form for this, however.

Please clarify what your specific problem is. Are you really assuming samples from `Beta(α, β)`? Or is your parameter `p` being sampled from that distribution and then your data sampled from `Binomial(p)`?

Comment: My sample X is from a distribution that's not Beta and 100% is not binomial.
It may or may be not scale-free, i.e. it is a distribution defined on N (w/o zero) with high dispersion.
A very good point here is that fit of the Beta param depends a lot by how X is rescaled into the )0,1( range. If you have suggestions on rescaling methods I will take notes.


Aim of this task is NOT to make predictions. I had excellent results with the code I posted BUT I noticed it doesn't help to provide conf.intervals, for example. Also I was curious about performances in different languages.

Comment: I was afraid that you knew what you were doing! With these clarifications and particularly with your need for a confidence interval, it sounds like you might do well to look into probabilistic programming. In R, particularly, RSTAN may be helpful. See https://mc-stan.org/users/interfaces/rstan for info. If MCMC techniques like that are too expensive due to you having lots of data, consider a bootstrap resampling of your current method.